# Why when searching in files for specific text in lines i'm getting strange results?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a backgroundworker dowork event

```
string CurrentFileWithPath;
        private void _FileProcessingWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                object[] CurrentStatus = new object[5];
                DirectoryInfo[] MySubDirectories = (DirectoryInfo[])e.Argument;
                for (int i = 0; i < MySubDirectories.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo MySubDirectory = MySubDirectories[i];

                    List<FileInfo> l = new List<FileInfo>();
                    CountFiles(MySubDirectory, l);

                    int totalFiles = l.Count;

                    CurrentStatus[3] = i.ToString();
                    CurrentStatus[4] = totalFiles.ToString();
                    _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);

                    string CurrentDirectory = "Current Directory: " + MySubDirectory.Name;

                    foreach (FileInfo MyFile in l)
                    {
                        if (_FileProcessingWorker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            return;
                        }

                        if (MyFile.Extension.ToLower() == ".cs" || MyFile.Extension.ToLower() == ".vb")
                        {
                            string CurrentFile = "Current File: " + MyFile.Name;
                            string CurrentFileWithPath = MyFile.FullName;

                            CurrentStatus[0] = CurrentDirectory;
                            CurrentStatus[1] = CurrentFile;
                            _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);

                            List<string> Result = SearchInFile(CurrentFileWithPath, "static class FileShellExtension");

                            if (Result != null && Result.Count > 0)
                            {
                                CurrentStatus[2] = Result;
                                _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return;
            }
       }
```

Then the CountFiles method

```
private void CountFiles(DirectoryInfo di, List<FileInfo> l)
        {
            try
            {
                l.AddRange(di.EnumerateFiles());
            }
            catch
            {
                string fff = "";
            }

            try
            {
                IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> subDirs = di.EnumerateDirectories();
                if (subDirs.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subDirs)
                        CountFiles(dir, l);
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                string yyy = "";
            }
        }
```

The backgroundworker progresschanged event

```
private void _FileProcessingWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (typeof(object[]) == e.UserState.GetType())
            {
                object[] StatusMsg = (object[])e.UserState;
                if (5 == StatusMsg.GetLength(0))
                {
                    label2.Text = StatusMsg[4].ToString();
                    label4.Text = StatusMsg[3].ToString();

                    if (StatusMsg[0] != null && StatusMsg[1] != null)
                    {
                        lblCurrentDirectory.Text = StatusMsg[0].ToString();
                        lblStatus.Text = StatusMsg[1].ToString();
                    }
                    if (StatusMsg[2] != null)
                    {
                        if (StatusMsg[2].GetType() == typeof(List<string>))
                        {
                            List<string> l = (List<string>)StatusMsg[2];

                            for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
                            {
                                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add("Directory: " + lblCurrentDirectory.Text + "In File: " + lblStatus.Text + l[i]);
                                w.WriteLine("Directory: " + lblCurrentDirectory.Text + "In File: " + lblStatus.Text + l[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And last the method SearchInFiles where i search in each .cs file in each line for a match:

```
private List<string> SearchInFile(string fileToSearch, string textToSearch)
        {
            List<string> l = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(fileToSearch))
                {
                    if (line.Contains(textToSearch))
                        l.Add(line);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                string fff = err.ToString();
            }

            return l;
        }
```

In this case i'm searching for the string: "static class FileShellExtension"

```
List<string> Result = SearchInFile(CurrentFileWithPath, "static class FileShellExtension");
```

I'm also writing the results to a text file.
I know that "static class FileShellExtension" exist in one or two files.
But when i'm doing the search i'm getting too many results many of them identical many of them not logic i'm getting the results in files where it's not exist at all.

This is part of the results from the text file i'm writing it to:

> Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Program.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: ShellContextMenuIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Resources.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: smscIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SnowFlakeIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SnowFlakeIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SnowFlakeIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SnowFlakeIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SocialHardwareIn File: Current File: AssemblyInfo.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SocialHardwareIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SocialHardwareIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SocialHardwareIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SocialHardwareIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SocialHardwareIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: SpeechRecognizerIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: AssemblyInfo.cs    static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Form1.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Statistic.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.001In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Program.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Resources.Designer.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Logger.cs  static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Speech_Recognition_Version_1.002In File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs   static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: AssemblyInfo.cs static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension
>   Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension

If i will take for example the result line:

Directory: Current Directory: Splash Screen With Progress BarIn File: Current File: Settings.Designer.cs    static class FileShellExtension

I checked a lot of times there is no any text "static class FileShellExtension" in the Settings.Designer.cs

I can't figure out why i'm getting so many identical results and in so many places and files it's not exist.

I do want to get more then one result if there are in in a file. For example if in a file Form1.cs there is 5 lines that contains "static class FileShellExtension" then write to the text file the 5 lines the complete 5 lines.

But what i'm getting now is a complete mess.

You can see the content of the text file better here: http://textuploader.com/5n5f4

Comment: What happens if you take a file it says its in but you think its not, and run it on that to step through it, do you get the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think the problem may be your `CurrentStatus` object. You should move this definition `object[] CurrentStatus = new object[5];` inside the loop. As you have it now, when you find your first occurence, you set `CurrentStatus[2] = Result;` and it stays that way all the time.

As an alternative, set `CurrentStatus[2] = null;` if Result is null or Result.Count is 0